# Is there a way to store many JID's?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

i have about 100 email id's of clients for my chat bot. Can i make an array or smthng of JID's to store many emails?
Thank you.

Comment: The answer is yes.  Would you like to ask a more specific question?

Comment: i have to group chat with about 100 people. i am the admin, i can send messages. but they can't reply to me. the can reply to the bot which will give pre-stored answers.
now i have to add JID's of these people in my code. i want a short method for it, instead of creating a JID variable for each email id.Thanks for such a quick reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in the [App Engine Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/); you could create entities for your users as follows (you'll only need to do this once for each user):

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity allowedUser = new Entity("AllowedUser");
allowedUser.setProperty("JID", "[[ user's JID ]]");
datastore.put(allowedUser);
```

Then, in your code, you can see whether a user is allowed to access by checking to see whether their JID is in the datastore:

```
Query q = new Query("AllowedUser");
q.setFilter(new FilterPredicate("JID", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, "[[ user JID to check ]]");
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
if (pq.countEntities(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1)) > 0) {
    // user is allowed
} else {
    // user is not allowed
}
```

Here, we perform a query to get all users from the datastore with the given JID. We also limit the number of results to no more than 1, since we only care if it's there or not (and there shouldn't be more than one with the same ID anyway). We then see if the result of the query has more than zero results; if it does, then the user must be in the table and they get access. If they aren't, then they don't.

Note that you can also add entities from the Datastore Viewer in the admin console, so if you didn't have too many, maybe it'd be easier to go that route instead of that first snippet of code.

Comment: You'll need to do it once for each of your users, yes.

Comment: then i can create a JID variable for each user. why this?

Comment: You only need to do this once, and it makes it easier to add users in the future. You also could do what I wrote in that last sentence, and add users from the Datastore Viewer, or write your own small admin interface to add them.